# Implementation of UIPageViewController with UICollectionViewControllers (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to implement a `UIPageViewController`, where you can slide between two `UICollectionViewControllers` (much like the iOS 8.4 music App). This is also supposed to use one instance of `UINavigationController`.

This is what I've tried so far:

Using Storyboard, I've added a new `PageViewController`, in which I have conformed to the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` as well as the `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` protocols.

Using Storyboard identifiers, I have successfully been able to get this to the point where you can swipe between each view.

Here is some sample code to be more specific:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self

    let startingViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
    let viewControllers: NSArray = [startingViewController]
    self.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UICollectionViewController! {

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if index == 0 {
        return storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AlbumsController") as! UICollectionViewController
    }

    if index == 1 {         
        return storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SubscriptionsController") as! UICollectionViewController
    }

    return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let identifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier
    let index = self.identifiers.indexOfObject(identifier!)

    if index == identifiers.count - 1 {
        return nil
    }

    self.index = self.index + 1
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(self.index)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let identifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier
    let index = self.identifiers.indexOfObject(identifier!)

    if index == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    self.index = self.index - 1
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(self.index)
}
```

The problem arises in the gestures being lost/overwritten when swiped to the next view. Initially I can scroll the first collection view and tap on the status bar to scroll to the top, but as soon as the pageviewcontroller swipes over to the next collection view, this gesture stops working and now neither collection view responds to the "scroll to top" gesture.

I have also heard using a scrollview is possible, but I wasn't convinced that this implementation would be more appropriate that using a `UIPageViewController`.

Current research suggests that the gestures are affected by the 'data source' of the PageViewController and must be altered in some way.

I have also embedded the `UIPageViewController` inside of a `UINavigationController` to achieve a shared navigation bar for both views. Now of course the navigation bar overlaps the `UICollectionViews` as they are not themselves embedded within a `UINavigationController`. To work my way around this problem, I've used this code below:

collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 64, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

Would anyone be able to give me some advice on how to properly re-create the 'swiping between two views' effect you get in the new Music App?
With my current implementation, I feel as it is not the correct way to achieve my goal, so I would greatly appreciate any help.